# Area calculation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, area

I am working on a paper and I need to find out the area of the region having color black from the image that I have attached.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YxRz.jpg)

I have done some processing by using threshold and complimenting the image.[Processed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qfSP.png)
Now I'm having a problem finding the area of the black colored region. Can someone please help? I'm new to `MATLAB`.

> Here is my code :

```
img1=imread('C:/Users/Allan/Desktop/unnamed1.jpg');
imshow(img1)

img1=rgb2gray(img1);
imshow(img1)

img2=im2bw(img1,graythresh(img1));
imshow(img2)

img2=~img2;
imshow(img2)

B = bwboundaries(img2);
imshow(img2)
hold on

for k = 1:length(B)
boundary = B{k};
plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 0.2)
end
```

Comment: Can you give more information about how your code is not doing what you expect it to? Does it cause an error or wrong output?

Comment: Nope it does not give any error !! It only converts the original image into the processed one that i have attached. So after this i need to know how can i find the area of the black colored region.

Comment: @AlSweigart i have provided the link for both the images in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `regionprops` or `bwarea`:

```
% take the NOT image
bw = ~img2;
% find individual regions
cc = bwconncomp(bw);
% find area for each black region
props = regionprops(cc,{'Area','Centroid'});
regionArea = [props(:).Area];
% find area of total black region
totalArea = bwarea(bw);
% plotting
for ii = find(regionArea > 100)
    c = props(ii).Centroid;
    text(c(1),c(2),num2str(regionArea(ii)),'Color','b',...
        'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','middle',...
        'FontWeight','bold');
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.will try that!!